Does the charged defect assume that electrons are localized around the defect? (in VASP DFT calculation)
After searching through various materials, I found that point defect calculations using VASP (DFT calculation) are based on the assumption that the charge of the cell itself is regulated by NELECT, and that the added or reduced charge is a defect. Therefore, I decided that the use of the term “charged defect” presupposes that the charge is localized around the defect.
However, I understood that the resonant defect state in the figure below (1) is a defect with a charge transition level inside the VBM or CBM. In such a defect, only one charge state is stable in the fermi level region inside the entire band gap. This defect formation energy form is reported in many literatures as well as V_I and V_Pb in Figure (2).
However, since this resonant state is not considered to be a localized state, it seems to be in conflict with the basic premise that the defect is charged.
I am confused as to how to understand this. I would appreciate your help.
[reference figure]
(1) https://speakerdeck.com/kavanase/tutorial-understanding-and-modelling-defects-in-semiconductors-with-vasp?slide=27
(2) Xue Haibo, Geert Brocks and Shuxia Tao. Physical Review Materials 5.12 (2021): 125408.



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Don't know about resonant defect but the premise that "charge is localized around the defect" is problematic. I did some defect calculations of charged defect and by analyzing the charge-density, I noticed the charge is not always localized around the defect and the extent of localization depends on the host, the defect and the charge. NELECT of VASP or tot_charge of QE assumes a opposite homogeneous background charge around the simulation cell. It's not like we are putting the charge at some exact point inside the simulation cell.

Are you asking whether VASP "knows" a calculation contains a charged defect (no, it doesn't), or whether VASP users typically interpret the simulation results like that?

@PhilHasnip
The latter. VASP users are generally asking if they should interpret the simulation results that way. Thank You for your comment.
